# Python - Creating Manager Hierarchy Columns with Employee Names and Manager Email columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, hierarchy

Am trying to create manager hierarchy columns using just Employee ID and Manager Email Address columns. The Name column has unique values while there are duplicates in the Mgr_Email column (ie each employee has one manager but a manager could have multiple reports in their organisation).

The data looks like this

```
Name         Mgr_Email          

Sally Po     donson.toh@abc.com
Sean Sea     sally.po@abc.com   
Jacob Hin    tim.buick@abc.com 
Tim Buick    sean.sea@abc.com
Kris Olt     cindy.myers@abc.com
Cindy Myers  sally.po@abc.com
```

and the desired outcome is this. There could be many levels of manager hierarchy and not just 4 hierarchy columns shown in the example.

```
Name         Mgr_Email          Mgr_Lvl_01           Mgr_lvl_02      Mgr_lvl_03       Mgr_lvl_04

Sally Po     donson.toh@abc.com  donson.toh@abc.com  
Sean Sea     sally.po@abc.com    donson.toh@abc.com  sally.po@abc.com
Jacob Hin    tim.buick@abc.com   donson.toh@abc.com  sally.po@abc.com sean.sea@abc.com tim.buick@abc.com 
Tim Buick    sean.sea@abc.com    donson.toh@abc.com  sally.po@abc.com sean.sea@abc.com
Kris Olt     cindy.myers@abc.com donson.toh@abc.com  sally.po@abc.com cindy.myers@abc.com
Cindy Myers  sally.po@abc.com    donson.toh@abc.com  sally.po@abc.com
```

I have tried this but it does not work

```
i=1
df['Level 0'] = df['Manager Email Address']

while df.notna().sum().ne(1).all():
    df[f'Mgr_Lvl {i}'] = df[f'Mgr_Lvl {i-1}'].map(df.set_index('Name')['Mgr_Email'])
    i+=1

df = df.drop('Level 0',axis=1)
df['Mgr_Lvl_01'] = df.loc[:,f'Mgr_Level {i-1}'].ffill().bfill()
```

Appreciate any help I could get, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Follow-uo note. The approach below works well for small datasets, but is not efficient for large ones. See this [much more efficient alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76780400/16343464), also based on `networkx`.*

You cannot solve this easily with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) alone, you would need to approach this as a graph problem.

This is your graph:

[image]

A useful tool is [`networkx`](https://networkx.org):

```
# make email address from Name
# (best would be to already have an identifier to map names)
df['Email'] = df['Name'].str.lower().str.replace(r'(\w+) (\w+)', r'\1.\2@abc.com', regex=True)

import networkx as nx

# create graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Mgr_Email', target='Email',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# find roots (= top managers)
roots = [n for n,d in G.in_degree() if d==0]
# ['donson.toh@abc.com']

# for each employee, find the hierarchy 
df2 = (pd.DataFrame([next((p for root in roots for p in nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, node)), [])[:-1]
                     for node in df['Email']], index=df.index)
         .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Mgr_Lvl_{x+1:02d}')
      )

# join to original DataFrame
out = df.drop(columns='Email').join(df2)
```

output:

```
          Name            Mgr_Email          Mgr_Lvl_01        Mgr_Lvl_02           Mgr_Lvl_03         Mgr_Lvl_04
0     Sally Po   donson.toh@abc.com  donson.toh@abc.com              None                 None               None
1     Sean Sea     sally.po@abc.com  donson.toh@abc.com  sally.po@abc.com                 None               None
2    Jacob Hin    tim.buick@abc.com  donson.toh@abc.com  sally.po@abc.com     sean.sea@abc.com  tim.buick@abc.com
3    Tim Buick     sean.sea@abc.com  donson.toh@abc.com  sally.po@abc.com     sean.sea@abc.com               None
4     Kris Olt  cindy.myers@abc.com  donson.toh@abc.com  sally.po@abc.com  cindy.myers@abc.com               None
5  Cindy Myers     sally.po@abc.com  donson.toh@abc.com  sally.po@abc.com                 None               None
```

Comment: yes, this seems to work! Very grateful for the help. Would you be kind enough to explain in a bit more detail how the code works?

Comment: I commented the main steps, let me know what is unclear to you.

Comment: ***Note**. The approach below works well for small datasets, but is not efficient for large ones. See [this much more efficient alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76780400/16343464), also based on `networkx`.*