# Speed up Networkx performance to create management hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, graph-theory, hierarchy

I have a dataset as below:

```
  Emp Mgr
0  E1  M1
1  M1  M2
2  M3  M5
3  M2  M5
```

So for each User(row) I need management hierarchy as:

```
  Emp Mgr Level_01 Level_02 Level_03 Level_04
0  E1  M1       M5       M2       M1       E1
1  M1  M2       M5       M2       M1
2  M3  M5       M5       M3
3  M2  M5       M5       M2
```

The output is something like: 
Emp > Managers (top level to his direct manager). 
So eg: For EmpA:  Mgr1 (CEO) - Mgr2 (Director) - M3 (Sr.Manager) - M4 (Emp's direct manager)

I am using networks for it as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74217339/16343464). There are 177K records with 2 root nodes. The total time to generate this hierarchy is more than 6hours. How can I significantly reduce the time taken by the script.

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Mgr', target='Emp',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# find roots (= top managers)
roots = [n for n,d in G.in_degree() if d==0]
    
df2 = (pd.DataFrame([next((p for root in roots for p in nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, node)), [])[:-1]
                     for node in df['Emp']], index=df.index)
         .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Level_{x+1:02d}')
      )
```

Comment: Why are you using pandas for this?  That's an enormous package, and I don't see how it helps you here.  What is the result supposed to be?

Comment: @priya please provide an anonymized version of the full dataset. It's impossible to comment on the performance without having the exact data at hand.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have used pandas to add the hierarchies from network graph into a data frame. I am not sure if same thing can be performed using some other way which is time efficient.
The output is something like:
Emp > Managers (top level to his direct manager).
So eg: EmpA - Mgr1 (CEO) - Mgr2 (Director) - M3 (Sir.Manager) - M4 (Emma's direct manager)

Comment: Thanks for the file, I'll have a look. The use of pandas is likely not an issue (and not the point) here, it's just a convenience to load the data, this won't impact efficiency. Btw, you mentioned 177k rows but your example has 16K rows, is this expected?

Comment: Somehow when I save this file as excel it loses the data. Complete csv file is at :[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GtrNXRz6Tueg-NjWe4WwYL5QxOeqj-2t/view?usp=share_link). The top 2 lines contains desired output. 

The desired output is to get the manager's hierarchy for all users (starting from top-level to user's manager). Each user can have upto different number of managers to top. Second sheet in excel, demonstrates 1 user's hierarchy from the demo records.

Comment: I gave it a try with the 16k dataset and it took me only 2 minutes to run. Are you sure your full graph doesn't have loops?

Comment: @mozway The 16k dataset takes 10mins for me. But the whole dataset (177K) is ongoing from 2hrs.
There is no other loop. The only 2 commands I am using apart from code pasted above is pd.read_csv & Joining data frame.

Comment: @priya I generated a new code, it runs in <2s for your 177k rows example. Please double check that it's working as expected. Also, a few nodes had several managers, I only considered the first one.

Comment: My point is that this data is not a good fit for pandas.  You clearly cannot do any kind of bulk analysis on the data (which is what pandas is for), because you have rows of variable length, which pandas doesn't handle.  You need to ask yourself, "what am I going to DO with this information?"  If you're just going to print it, you'd have WAY more control (and probably better performance) by formatting the individual networks on your own.

Comment: Thanks a ton @mozway. Actually, in anonymizing the data, it resulted in multiple managers, my actual data doesn't have it. 
There is a slight difference in the output I am expecting. For the users, with no managers I want Level01 to be Null and then User's name, for  Emp: 0flj52.5pl2p2@lB0f.ctm, L1=Null, L2=Emp.
Similarly, Emp: llizjlip.Mljj5pw@lB0f.ctm, L1=Null, L2=0flj52.5pl2p2@lB0f.ctm, L3=Emp. This is because the users with no manager shouldn't reach the top-level in hierarchy, rather be combined in Unknown group.
The script you shared saved all the time (runtime: 30sec).

Comment: @priya Then I'd suggest to post-process the output. It's easy enough to detect that a employee doesn't have managers.

Comment: @mozway I tried with replacing Null managers with Unknown. I will experiment a bit more in getting the desired result. Will get back to you if I run into any issue. But thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: If you do that, then "Unknown" will be the top manager of everyone. I'd suggest to open a new question for that specific issue (if needed) ;)

Comment: @mozway Actually it doesn't. It is "Unknown" only for the people where there is no manager listed. For rest it is the respective manager's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the logic using a combination of [`networkx`](https://networkx.org) and pure python with a recursive function:

```
df = pd.read_csv('demodata2.csv', skiprows=3, usecols=[0, 1])

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.dropna(subset='MgrUPN'), source='MgrUPN', target='EmpUPN',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)
G.remove_edges_from(nx.selfloop_edges(G))

parent = {}

# uncomment the prints to see which nodes have no or multiple parents
for n in nx.dfs_postorder_nodes(G):
    p = list(G.predecessors(n))
    if len(p) == 0:
        #print(f'"{n}" has no parent')
        pass
    else:
        if len(p)>1:
            #print(f'"{n}" has multiple parents ({p}), picking "{p[0]}"')
            pass
        parent[n] = p[0]

def get_parents(n):
    try:
        yield from get_parents(parent[n])
    except KeyError:
        pass
    yield n

out = df.join(pd.DataFrame([list(get_parents(node)) for node in df['EmpUPN']], index=df.index)
                .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Level_{x+1:02d}')
             )
print(out)
```

Output:

```
                                                  EmpUPN                         MgrUPN                                        Level_01                 Level_02                   Level_03                     Level_04                    Level_05                       Level_06                 Level_07                         Level_08                                          Level_09 Level_10 Level_11
0                                    2pjwtpk.zp@lB0f.ctm     Mlpkuz.Lpimwpubpp@lB0f.ctm                                 mlpji2@lB0f.ctm            pll2@lB0f.ctm       llul.zlvill@lB0f.ctm      l22llttp2i.p.K@lB0f.ctm    l2jt2it.jtpjtl1@lB0f.ctm     Mlpkuz.Lpimwpubpp@lB0f.ctm      2pjwtpk.zp@lB0f.ctm                             None                                              None     None     None
1                               Iz2pd_ibm.ctm242@DpF.ctm         zlvipl.Ku2wlp@lB0f.ctm                                 mlpji2@lB0f.ctm            pll2@lB0f.ctm    Flp5lz.j5tbl2i@lB0f.ctm     Mlximp.Dpzbip2z@lB0f.ctm        Blljij.will@lB0f.ctm        Lpp.Klmlppjztz@lB0f.ctm   zlvipl.Ku2wlp@lB0f.ctm         Iz2pd_ibm.ctm242@DpF.ctm                                              None     None     None
2                                  2Z.zzw.tj5pp@lB0f.ctm      jpppp20fp.lpipiz@lB0f.ctm                          0flj52.5pl2p2@lB0f.ctm  wlp2.zi20fllip@lB0f.ctm  jpppp20fp.lpipiz@lB0f.ctm        2Z.zzw.tj5pp@lB0f.ctm                        None                           None                     None                             None                                              None     None     None
3                                      IlM01w23@lB0f.ctm  Fpl2jizpk.ll20ft0f5l@lB0f.ctm                                 mlpji2@lB0f.ctm            pll2@lB0f.ctm      Kpiz.Ltvpjt2@lB0f.ctm          pt2.ljki2z@lB0f.ctm      Luklz.tbtpzk2@lB0f.ctm  Fpl2jizpk.ll20ft0f5l@lB0f.ctm        IlM01w23@lB0f.ctm                             None                                              None     None     None
4                                      zbp2plux@lB0f.ctm          Ml2ppz5.wtpl@lB0f.ctm                                 mlpji2@lB0f.ctm            pll2@lB0f.ctm    Xppxpz.0fttlpp@lB0f.ctm      Lipzbpj.D5tkpp@lB0f.ctm  0f5pizjil2.Kpu2p2@lB0f.ctm          Ml2ppz5.wtpl@lB0f.ctm        zbp2plux@lB0f.ctm                             None                                              None     None     None
...                                                  ...                            ...                                             ...                      ...                        ...                          ...                         ...                            ...                      ...                              ...                                               ...      ...      ...
177920  5idplki_zlijtu_lm.zumijtmtlifp.0ft.jl242@DpF.ctm   2tz5i5ijt.Mijzuzumi@lB0f.ctm                                 mlpji2@lB0f.ctm            pll2@lB0f.ctm    jlklz5i.Upzlkl@lB0f.ctm  zpii0f5ipt5.Kimtjt@lB0f.ctm      Ji2.2tz5iklwl@lB0f.ctm      2tz5ijlkl.2lkl2l@lB0f.ctm  jlkl5ipt.2iz5i@lB0f.ctm     2tz5i5ijt.Mijzuzumi@lB0f.ctm  5idplki_zlijtu_lm.zumijtmtlifp.0ft.jl242@DpF.ctm     None     None
177921                    zlijtb_p2tmt.0ft.jl242@DpF.ctm                            NaN                  zlijtb_p2tmt.0ft.jl242@DpF.ctm                     None                       None                         None                        None                           None                     None                             None                                              None     None     None
177922    zlijt.kti0f5i.553_0fl2t2-ijz.0ft.jl242@DpF.ctm                            NaN  zlijt.kti0f5i.553_0fl2t2-ijz.0ft.jl242@DpF.ctm                     None                       None                         None                        None                           None                     None                             None                                              None     None     None
177923                   zlijtu_2dk2pj.0ft.jl242@DpF.ctm        0f5ijlkl.Kiz5i@lB0f.ctm                                 mlpji2@lB0f.ctm            pll2@lB0f.ctm    jlklz5i.Upzlkl@lB0f.ctm     Mlzl5lpu.Klwlzp@lB0f.ctm    p2ujl.jlkl5lz5i@lB0f.ctm          2ukit.jl2lkl@lB0f.ctm  0f5ijlkl.Kiz5i@lB0f.ctm  zlijtu_2dk2pj.0ft.jl242@DpF.ctm                                              None     None     None
177924                 pkljltkl_zj2pj.0ft.jl242@lB0f.ctm                            NaN               pkljltkl_zj2pj.0ft.jl242@lB0f.ctm                     None                       None                         None                        None                           None                     None                             None                                              None     None     None

[177925 rows x 13 columns]
```

Running time for 177K rows:

```
1.44 s ± 255 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```